# Make a POST request to another site, setting some headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, http, http-headers

I want (in my rails app) to submit a post request to another site, setting some headers, when the user clicks a button.  I want the user to be sent to the other site (rather than just have a request in the background or something).

I'm a bit stuck: my understanding so far is

a) Regular form submission (which handles the POST) can't set headers, so i can't just have a regular form on the page.

b) I could set headers in the controller, make the button go to that action, then send the request from there, but i can't do a POST redirect_to so this isn't possible.

Are either of the above possible after all?  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: inside a form it's clear. otherwise use ruby for that 'http/net' ...

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "it's clear"?  The way i understand it, i can use "http/net" to read the contents of a page, but not to redirect the user to that page with a POST request.  is that not the case?

Comment: in the lib http/net are also methods for post, get content. inside forms means just having a <form> tag with a foreign url :)

Comment: Re the form:  So can you set headers in the form then?  Because i thought you couldn't.  Re net/http: I know that i can make a post request with net/http, but it was my understanding that i can't redirect the user to a different site with a POST request.

Comment: 1. you can handle the submit form and process it with jquery, add headers and then send.